# Bridge Becomes Unresponsive (must reboot)

Tags: linux, bridge, dsa

We noticed in some of our hardware that our switch (an integrated KSZ9477) stops responding, with the logs showing the following:

```
[ 9585.977985] ksz9477-switch 0-005f port1: Link is Down
[ 9585.983206] br0: port 2(port1) entered disabled state
[ 9585.993337] ksz9477-switch 0-005f port1: failed (err=-11) to del object (id=2)
[12664.128536] Microchip KSZ9477 dsa-0.0:01: Master/Slave resolution failed
```

When the bridge port goes down, it is impossible to stop/restart the systemd network. A reboot is the only workaround we have.

I searched for both "entered disabled state" and "Master/Slave resolution failed", and I see people reporting without seeing a common/cohesive root cause.

Any idea of why a switch port would enter into a disabled state, and what does "Master/Slave resolution failed" means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you have some more info?

```
for i in $(brctl show|awk '{print $4}'|grep -v id) ; do ethtool $i; echo " # " ;ifconfig $i; done
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/548066)

Comment: Yes, you are right and sorry.  
The loop would show possible interface errors and the state of the NICs. So maybe the asker will see the failure and can act.